# onPause will not fire in my listActivity - Android

Tags: android, gridview, listactivity, onpause

I have a GridView in a ListActivity and I need the GridView to destroy itself when done to free up resources. onPause and onDestroy are never called when I click an item. How do I make them fire? Here is my code:

```
public class ViewOutfitsActivity extends ListActivity {

    public static final String TAG = ChooseStickersActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private int mMenuId;
    dbhelper db;
    List<Outfit> mListContents;
    Context ctx;

    private void setMmenuId() {
        mMenuId = 0;
        // You can be pretty confident that the intent will not be null here.
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        // Get the extras (if there are any)
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            if (extras.containsKey("menuId")) {
                mMenuId = extras.getInt("menuId");
            }
        }
    }

    private void finishMyActivity(){
        this.finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridviewViewOutfits);
        int count = gridView.getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            ImageView v = (ImageView) gridView.getChildAt(i);
            if (v != null) {
                if (v.getDrawable() != null) v.getDrawable().setCallback(null);
            }
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridviewViewOutfits);
        int count = gridView.getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            ImageView v = (ImageView) gridView.getChildAt(i);
            if (v != null) {
                if (v.getDrawable() != null) v.getDrawable().setCallback(null);
            }
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_outfits);
        ctx = this.getApplicationContext();
        setMmenuId();
        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridviewViewOutfits);
        ViewOutfitsImageAdapter ia = new ViewOutfitsImageAdapter(this.getApplicationContext(), mMenuId);
        gridview.setAdapter(ia);
        mListContents = ia.getMlistContents();
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                try {
                    String imagePath = getOutfitInternalPath(position);
                    String externalImagePath = getOutfitExternalPath(position);
                    passClothingItemToViewSingleOutfitActivity(imagePath, externalImagePath);
                    finishMyActivity();
                    finish();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.v(e.getMessage(), e.getMessage());
                }
            }
```

Comment: Have you put log messages in to confirm this? I can guarantee that calling finish() will call `onPause` and `onDestroy`. Its likely the code in these methods is just not functioning how you expected.

Comment: @Doomsknight I have been testing with breakpoints in the debugger to confirm this. I am wondering if it's because GriViews are not meant to be in ListActivities